# Do I need the second "from" in the following sentence? I'm from Greenwich from London

Tags: commas, prepositional-phrases

And if so, do I need to put a comma before it? 
BTW I'd say "I'm from Greenwich, London."

Comment: The second 'from' is incorrect. Greenwich is ***in*** London, not ***from*** London. The same is true of any other place which is located within a larger place. The "Greenwich, London" usage is understood in the UK but has a distinct American tone.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no sign of research effort by the poster beyond asking it here. At English Language & Usage, posters are expected to include a summary of what they've uncovered on their own, to avoid forcing answerers to duplicate research efforts they've already made.

Answer (score 1):

No you do not.

"I'm from Greenwich, London," is the standard way to say it if you want to include the district and the city.

Only reason why another word would need to be in between the two is if your audience does not know Greenwich is in London, though it is implied. In that case you would say, "I'm from Greenwich, the one in London." or "I'm from Greenwich, which is in London."